# GET API call for Web Scrapping

Tags: python, rest, web-scraping

I am trying to automate pdf downloads from the  [website](https://portal.bhc.gov.pk/judgments/) which basically makes an API GET call when a download is requested from a page which itself is a POST call. Request header for the GET call is something like this[request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gta2n.png)

I am just wondering if its even possible to automate downloads from such a website in python ?

Any suggestion to go about it would be highly appreciated. Thanks

I have tried making simple GET requests in python but it seems its more complicated and it may even be restricted

Comment: Can you download the PDF if not logged in ? Going there I don't see any, and it would make sense to require to be logged in to download them I guess.

Comment: @R_D yes I can download the PDF without being logged in but I need to run a search which returns a list with download button for every item in the list

Comment: So we should be able to see a download link from the URL you posted ? I couldn't find it the other day.